# Splunk : re-run alert when count > 1 and alert only if both have count >1

Tags: splunk, throttling

I have an alert that is scheduled to run hourly. I've found that sometimes delay in logs population will trigger the alert, which I don't want....

I'd like to have a setup where if my first alert (let's say at :10 past) triggers, wait 5 minutes and rerun that alert (now it's :15 past).

If my first alert returns 0, then do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of running an alert twice, run it once (at quarter past), but *compare* the results of the last 5m to those from 15m-10m ago

Comment: I'm already comparing the results of the last hour to the results for the same hour, a week ago.  That way, I compare traffic that is comparable.